# Server farm with name not found during ARM template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy an ARM template that will provision the following elements:

- sql server
- sql server
- sql server db
- storage account
- app service plan
- 2 websites

I get the following error information:

```
RESOURCE ID: /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/servicename-int-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/servicename-int-appservice
STATUSMESSAGE: {
  "Code": "NotFound",
  "Message": "Server farm with name servicename-int-appservice not found.",
  "Target": null,
  "Details": [
    {
      "Message": "Server farm with name servicename-int-appservice not found."
    },
    {
      "Code": "NotFound"
    },
    {
      "ErrorEntity": {
        "Code": "NotFound",
        "Message": "Server farm with name servicename-int-appservice not found.",
        "ExtendedCode": "11001",
        "MessageTemplate": "Server farm with name {0} not found.",
        "Parameters": [
          "servicename-int-appservice"
        ],
        "InnerErrors": []
      }
    }
  ],
  "Innererror": null
}
RESOURCE: servicename-int-appservice
```

You can see the slightly modified template [Gist](https://gist.github.com/m7milan/c1e9e771bf34d952d4e0d48a6f6b4883)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get your template working. What I think is going on - you are supplying hostnames that are not acceptable by Azure, as it expects hostname like blablabla.azurewebsites.net

So what I've did (because I'm lazy) I've removed all the hostname parameters from the Microsoft.Web/serverfarms and Microsoft.Web/sites. It did deploy after that. You could probably figure out how to pass proper host names on your own, since you got this far. :)

here's whats working for me (I've removed all the pieces not relevant to the websites) http://pastebin.com/697bG27Z